# Can NVDA product certify web app for WCAG 2.0 AA level web accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, wcag, nvda, wcag2.0

One customer wanting their website to be WCAG 2.0 AA level compliance is asking the website to be tested using JAWS, Talkback and Voiceover. The compliance needs to be tested for IE, MS Edge, Chrome , Firefox and Safari (in Mac OS, Windows 7, iOS & Android)

We already have NVDA in our approved to use product list.

Can't NVDA alone be used to test our website and certify it for WCAG 2.0 AA level compliance?

Answer (score 3):

The Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) require that web content conforms to a set of success criteria; they do not explicit require tests with specific browsers and assistive technologies. For example, when you look at the [Techniques for WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/), each technique and failure has a test procedure that is independent of specific products (except for "technologies" that are proprietary, such as Silverlight, where they suggest the use of UIAVerify or Silverlight Spy).

So the question is actually about defining what user agent support means for your client's site. While NVDA is fairly popular, it works only on Microsoft Windows and it does not always interact in the same way with certain browsers as other screen readers (e.g. Firefox support versus Chrome support). Unless your client's site is a fairly simple site with just static HTML, I would not recommend testing it only with NVDA. On Windows, the combination of JAWS and IE (including Edge) should not be ignored. Mobile is a different experience than desktop or laptop.

Conclusion: If you are evaluating a non-trivial website, **do not test with NVDA alone**.